# How can I discard the time part of a Date in SQL query?

Tags: sql, mysql, date, time

I want get date like **7 Nov 2023** where there is no time part like **7 Nov 2023 00.00.00**

I am trying `SELECT getdate() AS Yesterday`, where I get time part after the date, which I do not need. example below `7 Nov 2023 11:26:55.000`